# Facebook "like" button which likes another page/URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a list of links and on each individual page there's a "like" button to "like" that page. But I want a "like" button next to each link in the list which will like the URL of the link next to it (just like it would if you clicked on the link and then the "like" button).

### How do I do this?

To create the button on each individual page I use the following code:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
     FB.init({appId: '*****', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
};
</script>

<div class="share_button btn_fb">
<fb:like layout="button_count" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the iframe version of the Like Button, rather than FBML. The iframe requires that you pass the url as part of the query string.

You can generate the iframe code [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Comment: Your answer and @bsimic's answer works perfectly. I don't know which to give correct answer to. Which is more correct? Which is less likely to generate a "confirm" on the "like" button? Note: We're using the transitional doctype.

Comment: Well Facebook are in the process of deprecating FBML. See [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/). Currently they both work, but in the future, FBML may not.

Comment: Thanks, on facebook documentation pages, there is no mention that liking another page would be not allowed. But just to be sure, cannot Facebook consider it as hack when I like another URL, is it OK doing such like buttons?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
<fb:like layout="button_count" href="http://yourlink.com" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
```

Where the href attribute is the URL you want the person to 'like'

Comment: Your answer and @ConnelWatkins' answer works perfectly. I don't know which to give correct answer to. Which is more correct? Which is less likely to generate a "confirm" on the "like" button? Note: We're using the transitional doctype.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="[put the url here]" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

Just replace the `[put the url here]` with the url you want to like and then paste the full code to the place where you want the like button.

Comment: is there any difference between this and @bsimic's answer?

Comment: there isn't any difference but i suggested this answer because if you are storing the urls in a db the you can easily create multiple like buttons using this general script instead of going to the FB site and generating the code individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just go to the Facebook Developers page here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

and it will generate the code for you, and you can just copy it into your site. I just re-verified it. It works nicely.

This will generate the code(or something similar) that @Coding-Freak wrote.

Comment: Well, I'll be generating this code dynamically (as anyone should if it's a list). There will be a LOT of buttons on a LOT of lists

Comment: That's not a problem. Just go to the site and generate the FB Like button code once. Then you can see the syntax, and how to embed your own URLs into a like button. Then you can simply copy/generate it as you need.