# connect like button to facebook fan page page

Tags: web, facebook-like

how can I connect the like button on a website with my new facebook company fan page? 
Isn't it possible to avoid having two different like buttons (one on website, one on facebook site)?

The like button on my website already has about 73 likers. I would like them to merge with the new facebook site.

Answer (score 0):

Like is per URL. If a user likes your website, it doesn't mean she likes your page, and vice versa. So FB wouldn't let you "migrate" likes.

Comment: Would it help, to reset the like button on the website and point its href to the fan page?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203164/facebook-like-button-which-likes-another-page-url